# How Can i disable <Link href="" /> in next JS on various conditions

Tags: javascript, next.js, hyperlink

My Code is That : 
<Link href={`/blog/${bdetails.id - 1}`}>
Prev Post



<Link href={`/blog/${bdetails.id + 1}`}>
Next Post

**Question**

I want to navigate to next post or previous post on condition.

**Explanation**

I have an array of blogData in my **[id].js** and achieving bdetails.id by using props to my this component which is  **BlogDetailContent.js** .
I want to control previous and next post by simple disabling previous button on bdetails.id === 1 , here button should be disabled. I want it by simple ternary operator or by if condition. I do not want to use **next/router** . It should be using by function component not by class component.

Answer (score 28):

## For Nextjs 12+

You need to add the following on that condition

1. `pointer-event: none` to disable mouse events.
2. `aria-disabled="true"` to give the screen readers insight that the link is disabled.
3. `tabIndex="-1"` to disable keyboard navigation.

### With CSS

`css`

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

`jsx`

```
<Link 
  href='/link' 
  className={someCondition ? 'disabled' : ''} 
  aria-disabled={someCondition} 
  tabIndex={someCondition? -1 : undefined}
>Link</Link>
```

### With TailwindCSS

`jsx`

```
<Link 
  href='/link' 
  className={someCondition ? 'pointer-events-none' : ''} 
  aria-disabled={someCondition} 
  tabIndex={someCondition? -1 : undefined}
>Link</Link>
```

### With Inline style

`jsx`

```
<Link 
  href='/link' 
  style={
    'pointer-event' someCondition ? 'none' : 'auto'
  } 
  aria-disabled={someCondition} 
  tabIndex={someCondition? -1 : undefined}
>Link</Link>
```

## Old answer which for Older versions

You need to add `a` tag inside the `Link` tag and just use a class that gives `pointer-events: none;` for the element and conditionally add or remove this class.

```
<Link 
  href='/link' 
  passHref>
  <a className={someCondition ? 'disabled' : ''}>Link</a>
</Link>
```

`CSS`

```
.disabled{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I did it , but now the next button is creating an issue for me , i have an array of object and want to access it , but it gives undefined. i want to go on URL as http://localhost:3000/blog/6/. and i have 6 objects in an array. but when i write blogDetails.id + 1 , it accross the my objects as which i do not want .URL becomes as : http://localhost:3000/blog/7/

Comment: if applying custom classname on `Link` does not work, try using an `anchor` tag as a child for it too; like so: `<Link href="/somewhere" passHref><a className="YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS">YOUR TEXT</a></Link>`

Comment: @AliBaghban, Thanks for notifying me, I just update the answer.

Comment: This solution doesn’t prevent users from clicking the link using something else than their mouse (e.g. using the keyboard). It is also bad for accessibility since screen readers won’t be able to know that the link is disabled.

Comment: @Nicolapps, I just updated my answer, thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 3):

You can no longer use `<a>` inside `<Link>` in Next.js. So, you can disable link clicking like this.

```
<Link
  href={url}
  target="_blank"
  style={{
    pointerEvents: (condition) ? "none" : "auto",
  }}>
  Your Conditional Link
</Link>
```